# How to change style of any class in Bootstrap while using it offline(CDN)..?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

What are the possible ways to change a pre-defined class style in bootstarp while using it through CDN for example if i am using a navigation than how can i change its style which is defined in navigation class?

Comment: You can override any CSS style from any library as long as you define your style *after* you include the library. Use your own stylesheet reference or include it right in your page with a `<style>` tag.

Comment: I am working on my own website, most of the time i have to change or make some modification in style of bootstrap classes so please suggest me is it good practice to include my own style sheet or to make changes in CSS of bootstrap after download.

Answer (score 0):

on your page write the style you want inside

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
    .navbar 
    {

    }
</style>
```

tags after the CDN link. That should do it. 
If you want your style to be applied no matter where you put it on the page (no matter the order of it) you can use `!important` which will have the style always be applied no matter where it appears in the CSS document or on your HTML page.

Example to the bootstrap navbar class:

```
.navbar {
                 display: block !important;
            }
```